# Javascript: How to prevent adding div on document.execcommand("insertText") on `contentEditable` element?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to prevent auto adding `div` or any other tag when executing `insertText` on `contentEditable` div?

For instance I want to copy and paste a paragraph containing many `newLine` character:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt
```

it has 4 lines. When I copy and paste it into my `contentEditable` div, it became:

```
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</div>
<div>consectetur adipiscing elit,</div>
<div>sed do eiusmod tempor</div>
<div>incididunt</div>
```

I works fine with `insertHTML`, but the problem is that sometimes I want to copy and paste `HTML elements too` like:

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>Hello world</p>
<div>Horayy</div>
```

I do not want to create html elements inside my `contentEditable` div.

How can I achieve this?

---

### NOTE

I can prevent adding `div` if I input `enter` key manually, but this case is different, I need to prevent it for copied text.

This is what I have done:

```
  const pastePlainText = useCallback((e: ClipboardEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (e && e.clipboardData) {
      var text = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
      document.execCommand("insertText", false, text);
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: its just a flag variable, I removed it and it still doing the same thing.